# How can I make BottomNavigationBar NOT stick on top of keyboard flutter?

Tags: flutter

So I wanted to make the sticking of BottomNavigationBar on the keyboard stop.
I have tried:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false; (or true both not working),
```

The problem with the bottomnavigationbar sticking to my keyboard is when I try to type something, the suggestions are not clearly visible as it was hidden by screen content and also it has a nested app bar on another page, which in-turn make it very difficult to type and see the suggestions, some scrolling is what i am looking for.

Here is my code:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

getUser();

//PostController().getUser(widget.auth.getCurrentUser());
pages = [Home(), Search(), NewPostPage(), Notifications(), Profile()];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
  body: Home(context),
);
}

Widget Home(context) {
var bottomOptions = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[];
for (var i = 0; i < widget.bottomItems.length; i++) {
  var d = widget.bottomItems[i];
  bottomOptions.add(
    new BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: d.icon,
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 3, 3, 0),
        child: new Text(d.title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
return Scaffold(  
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
      leading: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.motorcycle),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                    pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) => Finder(),
                    transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) =>
                        FadeTransition(opacity: anim1, child: child),
                    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
                  ));
            }),
      ),
  body: isLoading
      ? CollectionScaleTransition(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 10, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 10, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 10, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        )
      : PageView(
          controller: pageController,
          children: pages,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged, 
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), 
        ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    showUnselectedLabels: true,
    items: bottomOptions,
    currentIndex: currentIndex,
    selectedFontSize: 9,
    unselectedFontSize: 9,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        onTap(index);
        currentIndex = index;
      });
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

How to make it stop appearing when I try to type on my text-field?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: fwiw, I am still seeing this issue on web mobile at this point in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` property is deprecated. We need to use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` instead. More details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html).

Also, I tried to recreate your case but was unable to replicate the issue you mentioned. I took some of your code and used it my sample, as below:

```
return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
    leading: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.motorcycle),
    onPressed: () {}),
    )),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 0, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
              title: new Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.mail),
              title: new Text('Messages'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                title: Text('Profile')
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term'
              ),
            ))
    );
```

With above code, when I tap on textfield, the `bottom nav` didn't show and I was able to type in properly.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: `Flutter v1.22.4 `even with resizeToAvoidBottomInset false the bottomappbar or bottomnavigationbar is above the keyboard. This answer needs updating.

Comment: If you have **nested** `Scaffold`, check that your root `Scaffold` also has `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` set.  This could be overriding nested settings.

Comment: not working for flutter 2.5.

Answer (score -1):

Updated Solution is Simply wrappping your bottom navigation bar with Padding and set it to MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,

```
bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
  padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
  child: TextField(),
),
```